# Visual Studio Remove Unused Nuget Dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

i am struggeling for a while now with removing unused dependencies from bin output folders. 
I am for example writing a small .NET Wpf program which gets its data from a Web server. Therefore i installed the System.Net.Http NugetPackage to make my Get / Post requests. The Package Information is stored in the .csproj file. 
When i compile the project a lot of Dependencies are added to the output folder

- Sytem.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
- Sytem.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll
- Sytem.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
- Sytem.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
- ...

None of these dependencies are explicitly used in my program, means when i delete them from the output folder and start the application everything works as expected. 
I do understand that this Dlls has to be in the package, but how can i ignore them. Is there a way to ignore dependencies within a nuget package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to set copy local to false on the Dll reference.

I haven't worked on WPF projects but I believe this would still apply.

To do this expand the References node in the project, select the Dll and then in the Properties window set the "Copy Local" property to False.

This should prevent the Dll from going into the bin and also from being included when published.

One word of warning though, the application may work now but doing this creates a potential trap for future you or other developers.  If code changes down the road require one of these Dlls your application won't be so happy and then you'd have to remember to put the Copy Local back to True.